# parse.com - > how to do "or" between constraints

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to do the foloowing:

```
query.equalTo("m_user_send", user.get("username"));  or
query.equalTo("m_user_get", user.get("username"));
```

pay attention that it is differnt from the exmaple:

```
// Finds scores from any of Jonathan, Dario, or Shawn
query.containedIn("playerName",
                  ["Jonathan Walsh", "Dario Wunsch", "Shawn Simon"]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating multiple queries and then combining them using `Parse.Query.or()` :

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query1.equalTo("m_user_send", user.get("username"));
var query2 = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query2.equalTo("m_user_get", user.get("username"));

var orQuery = new Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);
orQuery.find().then(function(results) {
    //returns all objects that match either query1 or query2
});
```

See http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html for further documentation.

Comment: Is there any ordering to the results? i.e. by default do the results of `query1` come first and the results of `query2` come second?